# Java generic abstract class return type mismatch

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

I have an abstract class in java:

```
private abstract class Importable<T> {

    // ...

    public abstract List<T> validateData(List<Path> paths);

    public abstract void importData(List<T> data);

    // ...

}


private static class MyImportable  extends Importable<String>{

    public List<String> validateData(List<Path> paths){
        return // valid ArrayList<String>;
    }

    public void importData(List<String> data){
        // do stuff with data
    }    

}
```

Now, if I do this:

```
public Importable importable;
// ...
importable = new MyImportable(); // MyImportable extends Importable<String>
```

calling this works:

```
importData(validateData(myPaths));
```

But I don't like the raw `Importable` , so I added `<?>`

```
public Importable<?> importable;
```

doing so throws error:

```
The method importData(List<capture#5-of ?>) in the type ImportController.Importable<capture#5-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#6-of ?>)
```

while executing `importData(validateData(myPaths));`

and eclipse suggests me to cast to `List<?>`, which did nothing to solve the problem

Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT:** sorry if I wasn't clear, here is the actual usage

I will have many class that extends Importable with different types:

```
Importable importable;

switch(condition){
case 1:
    importable= // Importable<MyType1>
break;
case 2:
    importable= // Importable<MyType2>
// ....

}

importData(validateData(myPaths));
```

EDIT2:

I intentionally separate `importData` and `validateData` because some other class might want to `validateData` only

If matters:
I'm using eclipse 4.3 w/ Java 8 on Windows 7 x64

Comment: Not clear where's the definition of MyImportable?

Comment: Extends Importable<T> Seems pointless to have a generic base class, and then lock it into string in it's immediate descendant

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify my use case

Comment: Don't know enough Java to help, but your design is giving me the heebies. Be like extending List<T> to Be List<String>, List<int> ....

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the generic argument `?` with `String`

**EDIT** (taking the edited question into account):

I think that the following would be a better design:

```
switch(condition){
case 1:
    validateAndImport(someImportable, paths); //Importable<MyType1>
break;
case 2:
    validateAndImport(someOtherImportable, paths); //Importable<MyType1>
}
```

...

```
<T> void validateAndImport(Importable<T> importable, List<Path> paths) {
   importable.importData(importable.validateData(myPaths))
}
```

Comment: `public Importable<Object>` will give you an error that says `Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyImportable to Importable<Object>`

Comment: Updated answer, I didn't the class you where instantiating

Comment: Its mentioned in OP comments `MyImportable extends Importable<String>`

Comment: @Braj oversight on my part :)

Comment: You have just copied my answer :)

Comment: It turns out that is the case, but it was not intentional I assure you :)

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem

```
public Importable<String> importable;
// ...
importable = new MyImportable(); // MyImportable extends Importable<String>
```

as you know `MyImportable` `extends Importable<String>`

---

--EDIT--

as per you updated question, please try this one

```
abstract class Importable<T> {

    public abstract List<T> validateData(List<Path> paths);

    public abstract void importData(List<? extends Object> list);

}
```

and use

```
public Importable<? extends Object> importable;
```